# Possible to categorize fonts by license?

Tags: fonts, license

I recently switched from Windows to Xubuntu and am very happy with it so far.
I downloaded some fonts I want to add to my system now.
Some of these fonts have a commercial license; some others are for personal use only.
When i install those fonts, they appear by alphabetical order in the software i use them in (libreoffice, inkscape, etc....).

But depending the kind of project i am working on, sometimes i only want to use the fonts with the commercial license. Is there any way to sort the fonts or categorize them, so that i can immediately see in the software whether the font has a commercial license or not? For example not sort them by alphabetical order but using the license as a sorting criteria? Or maybe applying a filter or something like that?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

Comment: +1 Good question and a valid concern but AFAIK there's no way. I hope to be proved wrong by some great answer.

Comment: "I downloaded some fonts I want to add to my system now." from where?  Cuz... if it is 3rd party they should include a license file that you can search for. ALL the installed fonts in Ubuntu are license free. Even the microsoft fonts package is free for usage (decompiling is not allowed  though).